# Scale discrepancy in seaborn overplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have produced a plot from seaborn heatmap which looks something this this:

[image]

I want to over plot a line and scatter plot over it with the data:

| x_fitted | y_fitted |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.16 |
| 1 | 0.01 |
| 2 | 0.08 |
| 3 | 0.11 |
| 4 | 0.09 |
| 5 | 0.33 |
| 6 | 0.5 |
| 7 | 0.25 |

But the y-axis is not in scale when I am plotting it:

[image]

The code is:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 4))
ax = sns.heatmap(df_11, annot=False,cmap="Greens")
ax.scatter(x_fitted, y, label='Raw data', )
ax.plot(x_fitted, y_fitted, 'k', label='Fitted curve')
ax.set_xlabel('G')
ax.set_ylabel('G*-G')
ax.set_title('Calibrated Matrix')
ax.invert_yaxis()
```

Comment: Seaborn's heatmap uses categorical x and y axes. You could use a `ax.pccolormesh()` instead of `sns.heatmap` to set numerical coordinates.  See e.g. [Can I overlay a Seaborn plot onto a Matplotlib graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64407831)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by adding a second axis:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 4))

sns.heatmap(df_11, annot=False, cmap="Greens", ax=ax)

ax.set_xlabel('G')
ax.set_title('Calibrated Matrix')
ax.invert_yaxis()

# Create a twin axis on the right side of the plot
ax2 = ax.twinx()
sns.scatterplot(df2.secondary, df2.mean_primary, label='Raw data', ax=ax2)
sns.lineplot(x_fitted, y_fitted, color='k', label='Fitted curve', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylabel('<G*>')
```